# Issue in retrieving user data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the data from the firebase database where data is present inside user. I want to retrieve data and put it in model class. I want output as a text of data from the firebase and email it to the user, but the value which pass in email are null. There is problem in data retrieval.

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());

                database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users/"+user.getUid()+"/delivery");
                ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        post= dataSnapshot.getValue(RetrieveData.class);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                };
                database.addValueEventListener(postListener);
        }
    };
```

RetrieveData.java

```
public class RetrieveData {
    private String city, country, email, postal, state, street, username;

    public RetrieveData(String city, String country, String email, String postal, String state, String street, String username) {
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
        this.email = email;
        this.postal = postal;
        this.state = state;
        this.street = street;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPostal() {
        return postal;
    }

    public void setPostal(String postal) {
        this.postal = postal;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RetrieveData{" +
                "city='" + city + '\'' +
                ", country='" + country + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", postal='" + postal + '\'' +
                ", state='" + state + '\'' +
                ", street='" + street + '\'' +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

[Here is firebase database image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX3SI.jpg)

Comment: what exactly is the problem? Also show your database structure

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: @PeterHaddad I have attached the database structure you can check it out.

Comment: @AlexMamo  I have attached the database structure you can check it out.

Comment: I am getting null values in the output instead of values like username is gursimran and street is 221b street etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get that data, please use the following code:

```
String uid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference deliveryRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid).child("delivery");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String city = dataSnapshot.child("city").getValue(String.class);
        String country = dataSnapshot.child("country").getValue(String.class);
        String email = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
        String postal = dataSnapshot.child("postal").getValue(String.class);
        String state = dataSnapshot.child("state").getValue(String.class);
        String street = dataSnapshot.child("street").getValue(String.class);
        String username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", city + " / " + 
                 country + " / " + 
                 email + " / " + 
                 postal + " / " + 
                 state + " / " + 
                 street + " / " + 
                 username);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
deliveryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Having that values, you can do whatever you want with it.

Here is another approach using the object of `RetrieveData` class:

```
String uid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference deliveryRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid).child("delivery");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        RetrieveData retrieveData = dataSnapshot.getValue(RetrieveData.class);
        Log.d("TAG", retrieveData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
deliveryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: he has a model class, why would he retrieve each one in its own?

Comment: @PeterHaddad Added also the other approach.

Comment: Thanks @PeterHaddad!

Comment: @AlexMamo I want to access the data globally but when i do retriveData global the null values are found.

Comment: You cannot just use simply that data globally because `onDataChange()` method is called asynchronous. This means that you can use that data only in that method. If you want to use that data outside that method, you need to dive into asynchronous world and use my answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange).

Comment: Is there everything alright? Can I help you with other informations?

Answer (score 0):

```
 DatabaseReference databaseReference = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

     databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                //Getting the data from snapshot
                // user is a model class
                User person = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                Log.e("Üser Deatils", String.valueOf(postSnapshot.getValue(User.class)));
              //  https://console.firebase.google.com/project/samplechat-611e3/database/samplechat-611e3/data
                //add person to your list
                registerUserArrayList.add(person);


            }
            linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(UserActivity.this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            registerUserAdpater = new RegisterUserAdpater(UserActivity.this,registerUserArrayList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(registerUserAdpater);

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
 });

 Hope its help you to retrieve your all user details.
```